# MySQL Best select query from two table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database with following fields.

Table 1 (customer)

```
customer_id
age
name
salary
zip
```

Table 2 (zip)

```
zip
state
city
```

I need to get the data from both tables where age ?25. for that I need to write best optimize query. for that I have written following query.

```
SELECT a.name,a.salary,b.city,b.state From customer as a , zip as b
LEFT INNER JOIN ON  a.zip = b.zip
WHERE age >25
```

My problem is can I write this query for this purpose without join operation.

```
SELECT a.name,a.salary,b.city,b.state From customer as a , zip as b    
WHERE age >25 and a.zip = b.zip
```

what is the best query for this purpose. if I write select statement inside another select statement inside this is it good ?

Comment: LEFT INNER JOIN? Nice.

Comment: As i heard join operations are much more expensive. any reason for your suggestion ?

Comment: I found http://www.phpjabbers.com/mysql-inner-and-outer-joins-php45.html which suggests Left inner joins have no point?

Comment: Much more expensive than what exactly? A comma is just another way of writing a join, it is only more efficient if the WHERE clause filters rows out (and that is the same for JOIN).

Comment: Databases exist so you can JOIN stuff together. It's one of their most important operations. Relational databases help us extrapolate data. Trying to avoid a join because you read it's expensive is the definition of dumb. It's like buying a car, but you won't use it because it spends gas so it stays in your garage. Do not complicate things, simply JOIN the tables on `zip` if you need it and use the computed result set.

Comment: what will happen if I use my second statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to a question posed in the comments beneath the original question. From the point of view of MySQL's optimizer, the following queries are exactly identical...

```
SELECT a.name
     , a.salary
     , b.city
     , b.state 
  FROM customer a, zip b    
 WHERE a.zip = b.zip
   AND age > 25;

SELECT a.name
     , a.salary
     , b.city
     , b.state 
  FROM customer a
  JOIN zip b    
    ON a.zip = b.zip
  WHERE age > 25;
```

The second query is easier to read, and more flexible (in the sense that we can alter it in various ways more easily) - although of course no one would be so dumb as to store `age`!

Answer (score -1):

Joins are tidier/ easier to read. For mysql (and possibly other platforms??) in your example you could use USING(zip) however I've not used multiple tables in the from part and then using a join as well. I would probably have written your query:

```
SELECT a.name,a.salary,b.city,b.state 
FROM customer a
LEFT INNER JOIN zip b USING(zip)
WHERE age >25
```

Comment: what is the purpose of using keyword ?

Comment: @user3565768 To make things more confUSING. That's all.

Comment: I hardly think its worth downvoting?? USING is a simplifying feature thats all. It saves typing ON a.zip = b.zip thats all.

Comment: My downvote was for a different reason (actually two different reasons). Can you spot it/them?

Comment: 1. There's no such thing as a LEFT INNER JOIN. 2. (And this is more difficult because the question is a bit confused but...) This answer misses the point of the question.